# Java insertion sort method for strings not working

Tags: java, sorting, insertion

For a part of my homework, I am supposed to create an insertion sort method that takes strings from one array and sorts them into a new empty array that ignores duplicates. My code somewhat works using a very small test array of strings, but it doesn't properly work whenever there are two words with the same first letter. It starts by automatically moving the first string from the original array to the first position of the empty array and then sorts the remaining values by comparing to that. I know I need another loop somewhere, but I am having a really hard time trying to piece this together

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] words = {"big", "ALL", "zebra", "END", "great", "FOX", "quit", "episode", "zebra", "big", "all", "1"};
        System.out.println("Unsorted array: " + Arrays.toString(words));
        stringInsertionSort(words);
}

public static void stringInsertionSort(String array[]) {
    String[] sortedArray = new String[array.length];
    sortedArray[0] = array[0];

    int sortedElements = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Arrays.asList(sortedArray).contains(array[i])) {
            break;
        } else {

            int current = i;
            int k = i - 1;
                if ((array[i].compareTo(sortedArray[k]) < 0)) {
                    sortedArray[k + 1] = sortedArray[k];
                    sortedArray[k] = array[i];
                    
                    
                } else {
                    sortedArray[k + 1] = array[i];
           
                }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sorted array:   " + Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
}
```

}

Comment: I am not sure yet about the code, but shouldn't you have continue instead of break?

Comment: I put the break to stop any duplicates from being sorted

Comment: you wanna stop sorting the moment you find a duplicate or you just want to skip the duplicates? I think break will exit from the for loop and stop sorting the moment it finds a duplicate.

Comment: Ah no I don't want it to stop when a duplicate is found; I thought after the break it would just run the else{ } part and then keep on repeating the for loop

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for and if this solution is correct, but I hope it will give you an idea of what you should do - I tried to explain.

```
private void stringInsertionSort(String[] array) {
        if (array.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array is empty!.");
        }

        String[] sortedArray = new String[array.length];
        sortedArray[0] = array[0];

        int wall = 1;// indicates the wall - before the wall all elements are unique and sorted.

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            sortedArray[wall] = array[i]; // for the moment put the element inside the sorted array as the last element.
            int rightPosition = wall; // indicates the right position in the sorted array of the current element at hand. If negative, it's a duplicate
            for (int j = wall; j > 0; j--) {
                if (sortedArray[j - 1].compareTo(sortedArray[wall]) == 0) { // duplicate
                    rightPosition = -1;
                    break; // exit from the inner loop
                } else if (sortedArray[j - 1].compareTo(sortedArray[wall]) < 0) {
                    rightPosition = j - 1;
                }
            }
            if (rightPosition < 0) { // duplicate,remove the element from the sorted array.
                sortedArray[wall] = null;
            }else{ // not a duplicate, shift the element and put the element in the right spot
                for (int j = wall; j > rightPosition; j--) {
                    sortedArray[j] = sortedArray[j - 1];
                }
                sortedArray[rightPosition] = array[i];
                wall++; //forward the wall one position
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
    }
```

I don't know if this is needed for some kind of exercise you are doing, but if you want simpler solution - use Java Streams, here is the code :

```
Stream.of(words).distinct().sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```